# System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.InvalidIncludePathError'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, invalidoperationexception

I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An error was generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.InvalidIncludePathError': Unable to find navigation ' ApplicationUser' specified in string based include path ' ApplicationUser'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'CoreEventId.InvalidIncludePathError' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.'

from my repository class (this is the function):

```
public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string? includeProperties = null, bool tracked = true)
{
    if (tracked)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;

        query = query.Where(filter);

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProp);
            }
        }

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = dbSet.AsNoTracking();

        query = query.Where(filter);

        if (includeProperties != null)
        {
            foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProp);
            }
        }

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Where did I make a mistake? If anyone knows, then please help me solve my [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDvGB.png)

Comment: Maybe `includeProperties` contains a property that don't exist in the entity.

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what is wrong. You are running a query against an entity type and have provided an includeProperties string which contained a property name "ApplicationUser" where the entity in question does not have such a navigation property. This was likely a copy & paste error from another example on an entity that does have an ApplicationUser nav property to eager load, or in this case the navigation property has a different, or misspelt name.

Comment: The error message indicates that Entity Framework Core couldn't find a navigation property named 'ApplicationUser' when trying to include it in a query. Verify that 'ApplicationUser' is the correct name of the navigation property in your entity class.

Comment: @StevePy so where I change in code kindly exactly mention what line I write or modify to remove that error

Comment: @ManojAgrawal how i check that kindly tell step by step process

Comment: Start with the line that calls this FirstOrDefault method. It will have a parameter value for includeProperties that references "ApplicationUser", if the entity being loaded does not have an ApplicationUser property as part of it then remove this value from the includeProperties parameter. Otherwise check the entity you are loading for what navigation properties it has and ensure they are valid. This code is custom code, so if you didn't write it talk to the author about how it is intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on the following points to fix the given error :

- Check your code for typos in entity names, property names, or include
  paths can cause such issues.
- Make sure you are using a compatible and up-to-date version of EF
  Core for your project.
- Ensure that the entity type T being used in the GetFirstOrDefault
  method has a navigation property named 'ApplicationUser' if you are
  specifying  it in the includeProperties parameter.
- Check the value you are passing to the includeProperties parameter.
  Make sure there are no extra spaces, typos, or incorrect property
  names in the comma-separated string. It should match the navigation
  property names of the entity T.
- Ensure that the Entity Framework Core model configuration for your
  entity T is correctly defining the navigation properties. If you are
  using attributes verify that the navigation property is correctly
  mapped.
- Check the DbContext class associated with your application and make
  sure it has DbSet properties for all relevant entities, including
  ApplicationUser if that's what you are trying to include.